# php preg_replace separate dots

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a script which it gives me keywords from string. Code is:

```
<?php
$text = "This is some text. This is some text. Vending Machines are great.Баста - ЧК (Чистый Кайф)";
$string = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]/u', '', $text);
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string);
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string);
$string = mb_strtolower($string, 'UTF-8');
$keywords = explode(' ', $string);
var_dump($keywords);
?>
```

That's works great but I have a problem. This code returns me:

```
array (size=15)
  0 => string 'this' (length=4)
  1 => string 'is' (length=2)
  2 => string 'some' (length=4)
  3 => string 'text' (length=4)
  4 => string 'this' (length=4)
  5 => string 'is' (length=2)
  6 => string 'some' (length=4)
  7 => string 'text' (length=4)
  8 => string 'vending' (length=7)
  9 => string 'machines' (length=8)
  10 => string 'are' (length=3)
  11 => string 'greatбаста' (length=15)
  12 => string 'чк' (length=4)
  13 => string 'чистый' (length=12)
  14 => string 'кайф' (length=8)
```

Why the 11th array is **greatбаста**. I want to separate **great** and **баста** words.

I need something which replaces **.** to  dot and space (. ) if dot have something near.

Examples: 
This is a good day.It is sunny => This is a good day. It is sunny  **(replaced . to dot and space (. ))**
This is a good day. It is sunny => This is a good day. It is sunny **nothing replaced. Because the dot have space after**

Comment: Use `$string = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]/u', ' ', $text);` (replace with a space)

Comment: it worked, but I got an empty array's value at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first replacement should be performed with a space, and the last input should be trimmed.

Use

```
$text = "This is some text. This is some text. Vending Machines are great.Баста - ЧК (Чистый Кайф)";
$string = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}\s]/u', ' ', $text); // <= Replace with space
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string);
$string = mb_strtolower($string, 'UTF-8');
$keywords = explode(' ', trim($string));        // <= Use trim to remove leading/trailing spaces
var_dump($keywords);
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/ZdA07F)

I also guess you do not need a duplicate `$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string);` line.

Answer (score 0):

You only need 2 regexes.

Find: `[^\p{L}\p{N}\s.]+`
Replace: nothing

Find:  `[\s.]+`
Replace: a space

Then do an explode.

Sort of direct and to the point *!!*